# Show Custom Exception Message in TFS Build log

Tags: c#, exception, tfs, build

I developed a small console application to be used in a TFS check-in build step. If my application runs in my custom exceptions, I see them in the tfs log and the build is correctly aborted. But I want to display my exception message in the build log.  So our developers can get more information about the error.

Example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Start Doing");
        try
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine("Finish Doing");
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the awnser by myself. I used the wrong build step (batch). Instead now i use the build step CMD. Then the normal Console.WriteLine works for the Build Log.